# How to change Attributes on a Pop Up to equal to the Attributes of the Buttons that opened said Pop Up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

My project is a card game. Each Card is also a Button. When you click on a card in play, a Pop Up opens with a Card Image, a Scrollable Label of Card Text, and various Buttons.

[image: PopUp]

My current problem is trying to change the Image and Text in the Pop Up to match that of the actual Card Button information. I currently have the ability to change the information that shows up but only as the most recent definition of it. From what I understand this is because I'm redefining the class attribute, not an instance of the class attribute.

I've tried to do a def__init__(self, parameters): in the Card (Button Image) file, however this would crash anytime I tried to perform the draw method of the PlayMatWidget.

I think this may have something to do with Kivy Object Properties but I'm not entirely sure on how to use them for this exactly (largely since the buttons aren't created at runtime)

Thank you for reading!

Python File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import random

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollableLabel>:
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        text: root.text
''')


class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')


# Visual Representation of a Card or Deck
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class CardBackend:
    def __init__(self, name, card_art, effect_one):
        self.name = name
        self.card_art = card_art
        self.effect = effect_one


class Card(ImageButton):
    # Defining the Popup Window
    main_pop = Popup()
    main_pop.title = 'Inspect Card'
    main_pop.title_align = 'center'
    main_pop.size_hint = None, None
    main_pop.size = 400, 400
    main_pop.auto_dismiss = False
    main_pop.opacity = 0.8

    # Variables or Variables to Be
    card_text = 'ABCDEFGHIJK1234567890' * 100
    card_art = Image(source='test.png', size_hint=(.9, .85), pos_hint={'x': -0.18, 'y': .125})

    # Primary Child Widget
    main_box = FloatLayout()

    # Buttons
    play_button = Button(text='Play', size_hint=(0.32, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.01, 'y': 0.0})
    discard_button = Button(text='Discard', size_hint=(0.32, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.34, 'y': 0.0})
    close_button = Button(text='Close', size_hint=(0.32, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.67, 'y': 0.0})
    close_button.bind(on_press=main_pop.dismiss)

    # Scrolling Card Text Viewer
    card_info = ScrollableLabel(text=card_text, size_hint=(0.45, .8), pos_hint={'x': .55, 'y': .15})

    # Building main_pop.content
    main_box.add_widget(play_button)
    main_box.add_widget(discard_button)
    main_box.add_widget(close_button)
    main_box.add_widget(card_info)
    main_box.add_widget(card_art)
    main_pop.content = main_box


class PlayMatWidget(FloatLayout):
    def draw(self):
        # Create Backend
        # Draw Backend
        # Create Card() using Backend

        # Defining Card Data (Removed for imported Decks)
        backend_bewd = CardBackend('Blue Eyes White Dragon', 'bewd.png', 'One')
        backend_dragon = CardBackend('Dragon Egg', 'test.png', 'Two')
        backend_lava = CardBackend('Lava Golem', 'lavagolem.png', 'Three')

        # Creating Card Button Objects
        card_zero = Card()
        card_one = Card()
        card_two = Card()

        # Defining Card Title
        card_zero.main_pop.title = backend_lava.name
        card_one.main_pop.title = backend_dragon.name
        card_two.main_pop.title = backend_bewd.name

        # Defining Card Text for Scrollview
        card_zero.card_info.text = backend_bewd.effect

        # Defining Card Art
        card_zero.source = backend_bewd.card_art
        card_one.source = backend_dragon.card_art
        card_two.source = backend_lava.card_art

        deck_dictionary = {
            0: card_zero,
            1: card_one,
            2: card_two,
        }

        # Prototype Shuffle for top card
        # drawing = random.choice(deck_list)

        # Creating a Physical Card Object
        # drawn_card = Card()

        # OLD
        # Applying Card Data from backend to front end Card Object
        # drawn_card.main_pop.title = drawing.name
        # drawn_card.source = drawing.card_art
        # drawn_card.card_art.source = drawing.card_art
        # drawn_card.card_info.text = drawing.effect

        # Used to check somethings
        for x in range(0, 3):
            print(deck_dictionary[x].source)
            print(deck_dictionary[x].main_pop.title)

        self.ids.PlayerField.add_widget(random.choice(deck_dictionary), index=int(len(self.ids.PlayerField.children)/2))


class CardGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PlayMatWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CardGameApp().run()
```

Kivy File:

```
<Card@ImageButton>:
    size_hint: 0.8,0.8
    pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0.1}
    on_press: print('confirming press')
    on_press: root.main_pop.open()

<PlayMatWidget>:
    id: PlayMat
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: 'tron1.png'
    StackLayout:
        id: OppHand
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.1
        pos_hint: {'x':0.2,'y': 0.9}
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                source: 'background.png'
    StackLayout:
        id: OppField
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.4
        pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0.5}
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                source: 'background.png'
    StackLayout:
        id: cards
        size_hint: 0.6,0.4
        pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0.1}
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                source: 'background.png'
    AnchorLayout:
        id: PlayerFieldAnchor
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        size_hint: 0.6,0.4
        pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0.1}
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                source: 'background.png'
        BoxLayout:
            id: PlayerField
            orientation: 'horizontal'
    StackLayout:
        id: PlayerHand
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        size_hint: 0.6,0.1
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y':0}
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                source: 'background.png'
    ImageButton:
        id: PlayerDeck
        source: 'cardback.png'
        size_hint: 0.15, 0.15
        pos_hint: {'x':0.025,'y':0.05}
        on_press: root.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ everytime you override an `__init__` method, you need to call the super() method, if you don't do so for kivy widgets, they will crash, because they won't be initialised correctly, for python 3 i believe you want to do

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    …
```

2/ usually in kivy, it's easier to create a property and pass it by name, instead of passing parameters to init, this way you don't even need to override `__init__`, avoiding the error in 1/.

```
class CardBackend:
    name = StringProperty()
    card_art = StringProperty()
    effect = stringProperty()

…

card = CardBackend(
    name='Blue Eyes White Dragon',
    card_art='bewd.png',
    effect='One')
```

or, to use that in kv

```
CardBackend:
    name: 'Blue Eyes White Dragon'
    card_art: 'bewd.png'
    effect: 'One'
```

3/ in `Card` you define indeed everything in the class instead of the `__init__`, which means this code will be ran *when the class is defined*, not when an instance is created, maybe you actually want a function, not a class? or maybe you want to override the `on_press` method of your `ImageButton`, and put all of this code in it, using the properties of the card instead of the hardcoded values you use currently.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! A Function inside of the card class is exactly what I needed. Details in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I moved the creation of the Pop Up Box into a Function with the Card Class. In the kivy file, I bound the inspect_card() function to the on_press event of the Kivy Card Button.

Previously the Pop Up was being defined at the creation of the card. So the Pop Up would always have the information correspond to the latest created card, regardless of which card button I clicked.

Moving it to a function meant that the Pop Up is only ever created when that function is initiated, so all of the relevant information corresponds to the source information of the Button that called it. This way it doesn't matter whether the instance is inside the class or not because it will be redefined correctly every time it runs.

[Success Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qy9rt8PVA4&feature=youtu.be)

Card Class w/Function:

```
class Card(ImageButton):
    # Defining the Popup Window
    def inspect_card(self):
        main_pop = Popup()
        main_pop.title = 'Inspecting ' + self.cardname
        main_pop.title_align = 'center'
        main_pop.size_hint = None, None
        main_pop.size = 400, 400
        main_pop.auto_dismiss = False
        main_pop.opacity = 0.8

        # Variables or Variables to Be
        card_text = self.effecttext
        card_art = Image(source=self.source, size_hint=(.9, .85), pos_hint={'x': -0.18, 'y': .125})

        # Primary Child Widget
        main_box = FloatLayout()

        # Buttons
        play_button = Button(text='Play', size_hint=(0.32, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.01, 'y': 0.0})
        discard_button = Button(text='Discard', size_hint=(0.32, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.34, 'y': 0.0})
        close_button = Button(text='Close', size_hint=(0.32, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.67, 'y': 0.0})
        close_button.bind(on_press=main_pop.dismiss)

        # Scrolling Card Text Viewer
        card_info = ScrollableLabel(text=card_text, size_hint=(0.45, .8), pos_hint={'x': .55, 'y': .15})

        # Building main_pop.content
        main_box.add_widget(play_button)
        main_box.add_widget(discard_button)
        main_box.add_widget(close_button)
        main_box.add_widget(card_info)
        main_box.add_widget(card_art)
        main_pop.content = main_box
        main_pop.open()
```

Kivy Card Button with new binding and referenced properties for the Pop Up

```
<Card@ImageButton>:
    size_hint: 0.8,0.8
    pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0.1}
    cardname: 'stuff'
    effecttext: 'ABCDEFGHIJKL123456789' * 30
    on_press: print('confirming press')
    on_press: root.inspect_card()
```

(Prop Values listed are default, I change them below in the MainGameWidget before their brought to the field. I'll be moving most of this to the Deckbuilder functionality later)